# Sample data generation from existing data - Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, generator

I'm facing a what-am-I-looking-for problem again. I've got tracking data, meaning I tracked myself riding a bike a couple of times on the same track in order to have some test data. So I've got time-distance pairs. I want even more different ones, but want to generate them. I want the virtual test drivers to be both faster and slower. I don't want it to be a linear summing up algorithm.

Basically I just want a hint, what I could search for. Can somebody help out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try multiplying each data point's time value by a constant. If it's less than one you'll be creating a faster test drive, and if it's more than one you have a slower test drive. You can also fudge the position similarly if you want.

Comment: this is an affine transformation, y = Ax + b. b could be a small random number to help with changing the overall form/pace of the bike race.

Comment: seems to be a solution. to have it a bit more realistic I'd add that random number only every minute and interpolate the random change in between, so I avoid jumps in the performance of a rider. I think that will reflect the "racing behaviour" well enough. 

Thanks to everybody, I appreciate those suggestions and will have a look on the other ones as well.

Comment: just for your interest, I'll put the change on the distance value, as I want to keep discrete time values for allowing an easy way of comparison.

Answer (score 4):

You could check out [Markov Chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) for generating random data although it depends on how complex you want your distribution of data to be.  For a simpler approach, Reed Copsey's solution is going to be easier to implement.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [pseudo random number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) to generate random variations based off your original data.  Just provide a range +/- your measured values you'd allow the randomness to go, and generate random dataset values for time + distance.  This would let you generate as many test cases as you need.